# Discovering measures of a triangle

Tags: triangles

I'm having trouble studying for an exam with my brother. We are struggling with this exercise:

[image: a triangle]

We need to discover all the measures (b,m,h,a). We got a really weird result and we have no means to check if we got it right.

Comment: What result(s) did you get? Context is important. Do you have trouble finding all values or only some? Did you find $h$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

h = $3$ cm , by using Pythogoras' theorem

m = $9/4$ cm = $2.25$ cm

b = $15/4$ cm = $3.75$ cm

The values of m and b can be found using the properties of similar triangles.

a = m + 4 cm = $6.25$ cm